# How to force a 10mbps connection on a Linksys E900 or E2500 WAN port?

Tags: router, cable

I have a homemade UTP cable that goes from the ISP modem straight to a computer, since the UTP cable is not the best, I have to force the computer to go on 10mpbs, full-duplex (also turning auto-negotiation off) for this connection to work. And yes, I think we all know that using a better UTP cable is a suitable solution, but let's leave that aside for the sake of spreading knowledge.

What I'm trying to do is to connect that UTP cable from the modem to a Linksys router so I can connect more devices in that end, but I can't seem to find a way to force the same configuration on the router. **Is there a way to achieve this?**

I have available both a Linksys E900 and an E2500 to use. I've also tried installing Tomato firmware on both but had no luck.

Comment: Homemade cable.  Has this worked before?  Is it as likely to keep working as what it's plugged into?

Comment: Fix the cable...

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, cable works when connected straight to the computer, the idea is to have the router in the middle to allow more devices.

Comment: @DavidPostill :D

Comment: Ah, a possible confusion: "cable" means two things here, the homemade cable and the (cable?) modem.  If that's right, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Thanks for the correction. Hope I've clarified with the changes made to the question.

Comment: What are the results when you test the 8 wires in that cable with a continuity tester?

Comment: @MrEthernet, don't have a continuity tester, but since the UTP cable works just fine straight to the computer's network adapter, I'd focus on trying to configure the router. Let me know if there was a specific reason behind the tester suggestion.

Comment: "Let me know if there was a specific reason behind the tester suggestion." You have a homemade Ethernet cable that is admittedly "not the best". You are experiencing problems when using the cable and frankly, the more we know about it, the better. You're trying to work around an unknown problem, so if you can understand what the actual cause is, that might help you. It sounds like at least one wire is disconnected but if you're interested in working around this unknown problem, why not verify exactly what's broken first? The more information you have, the better. Also, how long is the cable?

Comment: Not only might that help you with working around this particular cable's limitations but, more importantly, it will help you to understand the mistakes you made when you terminated it, so that you can do a better job next time. If you're interested in troubleshooting Ethernet cables with continuity problems then I advise investing $20 in a basic tester.

Comment: @MrEthernet I really appreciate the intrest in the issue, the thing is that the only reason I mentioned the cable is to have a reason behind the poor connection. To be more specific, the UTP cable is an almost 50 meters long soldered CAT5 cable, it's almost certain that it's not going to work on 100mbps. The real question here is the one in the title, that is: to force the speed on router's WAN port just like one can do on a computer, given the cable whatever the reason is behind the poor connection. Again, thanks for the intrest. Hope I've clarified the reason behind the UTP cable thing.